# HTML/CSS - dd and dt

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my online portfolio and everything works except for this thing regarding `<dd>` and `<dt>`. I'm not a web designer so the problem is far from obvious for me, even if it's probably one of the easiest things ever.

This is the part of the code:

```
<!--Vector Art Gallery start-->

    <dt class="dt1"><a href="#"></a></dt>
    <dd id="page1">
    <div class="inner">
    <div id="slider">
             <img src="images/Photography/img1.jpg" alt=""  title="<h1>Title</h1>">
             <img src="images/Photography/img2.jpg" alt=""  title="<h1>Title</h1>">
             <img src="images/Photography/img3.jpg" alt=""  title="<h1>Title</h1>">
    </div> 
    </div>
    </dd>

<!--Vector Art Gallery end-->


<!--Editorial Design Gallery-->

    <dt class="dt2"><a href="#"></a></dt>
    <dd id="page2">
    <div class="inner">
    <div id="slider">
             <img src="images/Photography/img1.jpg" alt=""  title="<h1>Title</h1>">
             <img src="images/Photography/img2.jpg" alt=""  title="<h1>Title</h1>">
             <img src="images/Photography/img3.jpg" alt=""  title="<h1>Title</h1>">
    </div> 
    </div>
    </dd>

<!--Editorial Design Gallery end-->
```

Now, the first part works perfectly but the second doesn't. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: Instead of loading the pictures it just loads the icon it would load in case of a wrong picture url.

Comment: Sounds like wrong image path? Keep in mind that on linux servers `photography` and `Photography` is not the same

Comment: You can't store unquoted tags inside an HTML attribute: `title="<h1>Title</h1>"`. Always strip any tags before inserting values into attributes.

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements with the same ID on a page (#slider) Assuming you're using JS for a slideshow and that the script is targeting the `#slider` it may be doing something unexpected. Try changing the id and see if the images appear. Also, if they are two different galleries why are the image paths the same?

Comment: Thank you SO much Dre :) It worked. Also, the image paths were the same just to try the code out. But yeh, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's one of the following:

- pictures are not uploaded at all
- instead of `.jpg` the files are `.jpeg`
- the real path is `images/photography/img3.jpg` instead of `images/Photography/img3.jpg`
- the url is different (double check relative paths)
- the uploaded files have wrong chmod

Check if the image is accessable via the web browser and if the path fits.

Additionally, as    feeela said, you should not put unescaped tags into html attributes.

Comment: I double checked the path and everything else. And the first gallery works perfectly. It also works if I leave the first part blank, without gallery and, for example, just with text, and I just create the gallery in the second part of the code, in the Editorial Design gallery. But if I want to repeat the same gallery twice it doesn't work for some reason and I really don't understand why

Comment: You should really remove the `<h1>` from the title attributes and try again. If this doesn't help, you should consider providing the URL to your site.